# Overlay kde plot using Seaborn displot

Tags: python, seaborn, displot

I'm trying to recreate a plot that I made with seaborn `distplot` but using `displot`, since `distplot` is being depreciated.
How do I make the `displot` overlay the two columns?
Here is the original code to create using `distplot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'num1':np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=100),'num2':np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=100)})
sns.distplot(df1['num1'],hist=False,color='orange',)
sns.distplot(df1['num2'],hist=False,color='blue')
```

[image]

Here is the code for the plot using `displot`

```
sns.displot(data = df1, x = 'num1',color='orange', kind = 'kde')
sns.displot(data = df1, x = 'num2',color='blue', kind = 'kde')
```

[image]

Comment: If you convert the DataFrame from wide to long format, it should be possible to use `sns.displot` as instructed in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#)

Comment: yeah that could work.

Comment: `ax = sns.kdeplot(data=df1)` is all that's required get a line for all the columns. But you may also want to specify `common_norm` to match `sns.distplot`. `ax = sns.kdeplot(data=df1, common_norm=False)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In think your are looking for [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html).

```
sns.kdeplot(data=df1, palette=['orange', 'blue'])
```

Without any special layout I get this result for your example.

[image: simple kde plot]

I set the `palette` argument to define the colors as you did in your example, but this is optional.

Comment: Do it in one line with `sns.kdeplot(df1[["num1", "num2"]], ...)`.

Comment: @mwaskom Thanks a lot for your comment. I adapted my answer based on your hint.

Comment: All you need is `sns.kdeplot(data=df1)`. The only reason to specify the columns is if there are columns that shouldn't be plotted.